# Scala - How to convert JSON Keys and Values as columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parsing, key

How to parse below Input Json into key and value columns. Any help is appreciated.

Input:

```
{
"name" : "srini",
"value": {
"1" : "val1",
"2" : "val2",
"3" : "val3"
}
}

    Output DataFrame Column:

    name      key        value
    -----------------------------
    srini      1         val1
    srini      2         val2
    srini      3         val3



        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Input DataFrame :
        +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        |json_file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
        +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        |{"file_path":"AAA/BBB.CCC.zip","file_name":"AAA_20200202122754.json","received_time":"2020-03-31","obj_cls":"Monitor","obj_cls_inst":"Monitor","relation_tree":"Source~>HD_Info~>Monitor","s_tag":"ABC1234","Monitor":{"Index":"0","Vendor_Data":"58F5Y","Monitor_Type":"Lenovo Monitor","HnfoID":"650FEC74"}}| 
        +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


        How to convert this above json file in a DataFrame like below :

        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
        |file_path       |file_name              |received_time |obj_cls |obj_cls_inst |relation_tree            |s_tag     |attribute_name  |attribute_value |
        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
        |AAA/BBB.CCC.zip |AAA_20200202122754.json|2020-03-31    |Monitor |Monitor      |Source~>HD_Info~>Monitor |ABC1234   |Index           |0               |
        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
        |AAA/BBB.CCC.zip |AAA_20200202122754.json|2020-03-31    |Monitor |Monitor      |Source~>HD_Info~>Monitor |ABC1234   |Vendor_Data     |58F5Y           |
        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
        |AAA/BBB.CCC.zip |AAA_20200202122754.json|2020-03-31    |Monitor |Monitor      |Source~>HD_Info~>Monitor |ABC1234   |Monitor_Type    |Lenovo Monitor  |
        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
        |AAA/BBB.CCC.zip |AAA_20200202122754.json|2020-03-31    |Monitor |Monitor      |Source~>HD_Info~>Monitor |ABC1234   |HnfoID          |650FEC74        |
        +----------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+----------------+

//**********************************************
val rawData = sparkSession.sql("select 1").withColumn("obj_cls", lit("First")).withColumn("s_tag", lit("S_12345")).withColumn("jsonString", lit("""{"id":""1,"First":{"Info":"ABCD123","Res":"5.2"}}"""))
```

Comment: Hi @SCouto, thank you so much for the reply, its very helpful. Actually I have added Input DataFrame and Expected Output DataFrame in question. Please have a look and help if possible :(

Comment: I updated my cuestion with the new example, but it's the same, you just need to change the column names. Please test it and if it's ok, kindly accept my question so if any other person have the same question can find the answer quickly

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your json loaded into a DF as follows:

```
+-----+------------------+
| name|             value|
+-----+------------------+
|srini|[val1, val2, val3]|
+-----+------------------+
```

First you select  the whole values items:

```
df.select($"name", $"value.*")
```

This will give yo this:

```
+-----+----+----+----+
| name|   1|   2|   3|
+-----+----+----+----+
|srini|val1|val2|val3|
+-----+----+----+----+
```

Then you need to pivot the columns to become rows, for this I usually define a helper function kv:

```
 def kv (columnsToTranspose: Array[String]) = explode(array(columnsToTranspose.map {
    c => struct(lit(c).alias("k"), col(c).alias("v"))
  }: _*))
```

Then you create an array fo the desired columns:

```
val pivotCols = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

And finally apply the function to the previous DF:

```
df.select($"name", $"value.*")
.withColumn("kv", kv(pivotCols))
.select($"name", $"kv.k" as "key", $"kv.v" as "value")
```

Result:

```
+-----+---+-----+
| name|key|value|
+-----+---+-----+
|srini|  1| val1|
|srini|  2| val2|
|srini|  3| val3|
+-----+---+-----+
```

**EDIT**

If you don't wanna mannually specify the columns to pivot, you can use an intermediate df as follows:

```
val dfIntermediate = df.select($"name", $"value.*")

dfIntermediate.withColumn("kv", kv(dfIntermediate.columns.tail))
.select($"name", $"kv.k" as "key", $"kv.v" as "value")
```

And you will obtain the very same result:

```
+-----+---+-----+
| name|key|value|
+-----+---+-----+
|srini|  1| val1|
|srini|  2| val2|
|srini|  3| val3|
+-----+---+-----+
```

**EDIT2**

With the new example is the same, you just need to change which columns you read/pivot

```
val pivotColumns = Array("HnfoId", "Index", "Monitor_Type", "Vendor_Data")

df.select("file_path", "file_name", "received_time", "obj_cls", "obj_cls_inst", "relation_tree", "s_Tag", "Monitor.*").withColumn("kv", kv(pivotColumns)).select($"file_path", $"file_name", $"received_time", $"obj_cls", $"obj_cls_inst", $"relation_tree", $"s_Tag", $"kv.k" as "attribute_name", $"kv.v" as "attribute_value").show
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+--------------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
|      file_path|           file_name|received_time|obj_cls|obj_cls_inst|       relation_tree|  s_Tag|attribute_name|attribute_value|
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+--------------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
|AAA/BBB.CCC.zip|AAA_2020020212275...|   2020-03-31|Monitor|     Monitor|Source~>HD_Info~>...|ABC1234|        HnfoId|       650FEC74|
|AAA/BBB.CCC.zip|AAA_2020020212275...|   2020-03-31|Monitor|     Monitor|Source~>HD_Info~>...|ABC1234|         Index|              0|
|AAA/BBB.CCC.zip|AAA_2020020212275...|   2020-03-31|Monitor|     Monitor|Source~>HD_Info~>...|ABC1234|  Monitor_Type| Lenovo Monitor|
|AAA/BBB.CCC.zip|AAA_2020020212275...|   2020-03-31|Monitor|     Monitor|Source~>HD_Info~>...|ABC1234|   Vendor_Data|          58F5Y|
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+-------+------------+--------------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi SCouto, Thanks again, but the problem is, I have 100s Json files with Dynamic field, all the json files have different Pivot columns, So is there any way to do without hard code in pivotColumns?

Comment: You can do by extracting the inner fields from the Struct (this way you only need to know the struct name)


df.select($"Monitor.*").schema.names

Comment: Hi, @SCouto, Can you please help on this given rawData in last in question? Struct field of Json (ex: First) will be always the value of obj_cls to get it dynamically in case of different Struct Fields of Different Json Data.